# Using setOnClickListener on layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm pretty new in android and I was wondering what really happens if I don't use "setOnClickListener" in one of my Layouts because it seems that my app can still run properly without any errors. Can anyone explain me that to me?

example:

```
myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
myLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
myLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout2);
```

Comment: You don't need it unless you want your layout to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `setOnClickListener` to `this` it means that when a button or whatever your object is is clicked, then this activity will handle the event (basically decides what happens afterward).

Your code still runs because you don't HAVE to handle a click event if you don't want to. Not having an `onClickListener` will not crash your app.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you probably won't want a click event handled for a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setOnClickListener(this)` on a View tells that View that you want a callback (to `onClick(View)`) when that View is clicked.

If you don't care about receiving a callback when that View is clicked, you don't need to call `setOnClickListener()`.

Most of the time, you don't care about click events from ViewGroups such as LinearLayout.